# How to prevent electrical appliances from exploding

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, refrigerator, fire-hazard

I've been reading news lately that AC or fridge explodes sometimes and causes fire and death.

What are the other household electrical appliances that explodes ? How may I prevent this ? Is there any tool to find out at early stage and prevent this  ?

As far as my research goes , there are some environment friendly refrigerants that causes fire sometimes or if something gets stuck on it's way in AC or short circuit or sometimes the outside AC box also explodes. It's really a big deal

Comment: Citation needed... I've never heard of a fridge or AC exploding.  They have sealed compressors so the risk of fire is small.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - https://www.deccanherald.com/content/388415/injured-ac-blast-three-family.html

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: For the record: downvote b/c title and question misstate obvious facts presented in linked article.

Comment: I've never heard of one exploding but I have heard of overheating and causing fires due to lack of proper airflow.  Usually A/C and refrigerators have enough space and airflow that it's not a common issue.  Dehumidifiers however, are notorious for causing fires, often because people don't give enough space around them and the housing is usually plastic which is very flammable.  Every dehumidifier I have ever owned has been part of a fire related recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That news story is vague on what kind of "explosion" occurred. What it makes clear is that an electrical fault started a fire and the fire spread. What you can do is have knowledgeable people inspect your home wiring and appliances to ensure they are safe, and accept their advice regarding improvements. The "explosion" in your news story was probably a pressurized system rupturing under high heat, not a rapid exothermic reaction. All A/Cs have pressurized systems. No A/Cs (that I know of) contain explosive chemicals. Nor do any other electrically-powered home appliances.

Have your home wiring and electrical appliances inspected by a trained electrician and follow her advice on safety issues.

Do not store gasoline, propane, or other explosives inside your home.

Don't worry so much about explosions. Worry about old, neglected, poorly installed or poorly maintained electrical appliances in your home.  Those can and do start fires and kill people all the time.  Almost none of them explode.  When you buy an A/C or a Fridge or heater, READ THE MANUAL.  Read all of it.  Read all the safety warnings at the beginning.  And do EVERYTHING the instructions say.  If you have old appliances in your home that you did not install and you do not have the manuals, consider replacing them with new appliances, connected to new electrical circuits installed by a trained electrician, and read the manuals entirely, and follow all their instructions.  That is how you can protect yourself and your family.

Answer (score 3):

> A couple and their daughter died of serious burns they had suffered in
> a fire mishap after an air conditioner exploded due to a
> ***short circuit*** at their home at Mattadahalli in RT Nagar on Monday.

Understand that, all electronic devices should work fine under proper conditions, when you expose electronics to faulty enviroment they are due to fail.

What you can do to ensure this will not happen start with common sense :

- Ask for a an electrician to do a Health Check Up in your installation , to see if you have any faulty or not to code installation
- Read the Manuals and provide a proper place/installation for then
- Use the equipment for the purpose they were made, don't try to cook pizza with a stream-iron ( yes, that one you saw on some funny college meme.)

It is impossible to know if X or Y equipament will explode/short circuit, because that is an accident, you can take your time to prevent those.